# Compare days using Date objects without mutating them

Tags: javascript, performance, date

I need to compare two dates in Javascript, considering only the day (ie. not the time), but I don't want to mutate the original date objects.

I've come up with:

```
_isDayGreaterOrEqualThan(date1, date2) {
    const dayDate1 = new Date(date1).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    const comparableDate1 = new Date(dayDate1).getTime();
    const dayDate2 = new Date(date2).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    const comparableDate2 = new Date(dayDate2).getTime();
    return comparableDate1 >= comparableDate2;
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this, without using external libraries?

Comment: Creating another Date-Objects for `comparableDate1` and `comparableDate2` are not necessary because `setHours` also returns the timestamps you are calling with `new Date(dayDate1).getTime()` and `new Date(dayDate2).getTime()`

Comment: As Blauharley says, *dayDate1* and *comparableDate1* will be identical values (millisecond offsets from 1970-01-01).

Comment: You could do the same operation as a single line of code: `return new Date(date1).setHours(0,0,0,0) >= new Date(date2).setHours(0,0,0,0)`. Hopefully *date1* and *date2* are Dates. If they're strings, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not more efficient, but more elegant:

```
Date.prototype.onlyDate = function () {
    var d = new Date(this);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return d;
}
```

and then you can ask:

```
date1.onlyDate() > date2.onlyDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the timestamp and truncate it to multiples of `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`, i.e. days in milliseconds.

```
_isDayGreaterOrEqualThan(date1, date2) {
    const comp1 = Math.trunc(date1.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const comp2 = Math.trunc(date2.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return comp1 >= comp2;
}
```

As a side note: by convention, comparator functions return a negative number if the left argument is less than the right, a positive number if the right argument is less than the left, and zero if they're equal (this is the convention that e.g. `Array.sort()` uses if you pass a function as an argument). So you might want to consider this:

```
_compareDay(date1, date2) {
    const comp1 = Math.trunc(date1.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const comp2 = Math.trunc(date2.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return comp1 - comp2;
}
```

Comment: That will compare UTC dates since *getTime* returns the internal time value, which is a UTC offset. The OP seems to be comparing local dates.

Comment: Does that matter, though? The end result is still that one date is before the other. Timezone doesn't really make a difference, especially if we use UTC which is zone independent.

Comment: Yes. For someone in timezone UTC -08:00, 2018-05-15 12:00 is the same date UTC, but 2018-05-15 20:00 (i.e. the same local day) is 2018-05-16 04:00 UTC (i.e. the next day). Some places also apply daylight saving changes at midnight, which can also shift Dates using this method.

Comment: Ahhh, okay I see what you mean. Local dates do make more sense in this case.